# gcc fails with template recursion, while clang does not

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, clang, gcc4.9

Comparing clang 3.4.2 and gcc 4.9, which is correct for the following code?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct SelfRec {
    static const int value = SelfRec<T>::value;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << SelfRec<int>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

clang prints 0, gcc gives typical reached template max depth error.

Comment: Since this is probably undefined behaviour they're **both** correct.

Comment: With `-std=c++03` [both of them cannot compile this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe81f9447912690d).

Comment: It is interesting that if we make `value` a C++14 variable template then *clang* [starts to show compiler errors related to a template instantiation recursion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a91f97672a962775).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What could be the meaning of such code?  You say Clang prints 0, which is not shocking given that it compiled, but what does the zero mean?  Where did it come from?

Note that the `static const int value` is not a global static variable but exists for each `T`.  And there are infinitely many `T`s, so value should indeed recurse forever.  I don't blame GCC for failing to compile this, in fact it's probably for the best.

Comment: "And there are infinitely many `T`s, so value should indeed recurse forever." That’s a curious formulation. If `value` was initialized with `0`, and we added `static constexpr const int* addr = &SelfRec<T>::value;`, would that also ‘recurse forever’?

Comment: @LucDanton: would you argue that `SelfRec<T>::value` in the class is meant to refer to the value same value to which it is assigned?  I could buy that...though Clang still likes the code even with `-Winit-self` which I was foolishly hoping would produce some diagnostic...but it doesn't (neither does `-Wall -Wextra`).  My reading of it is that `SelfRec<T>` isn't defined yet, so must be defined, which is infinitely recursive.  But it seems that Clang is "smart" enough to decode this puzzle and emit constant zero (the only sensible value given the rules for statics not otherwise assigned).

Comment: Mentioning the current specialization that way is indeed possible. E.g. you can declare a copy constructor as either `SelfRec(SelfRec const&);` or `SelfRec(SelfRec<T> const&);`, they mean the same thing. You can add `using self_type = SelfRec<T>;` and so on.

Comment: A perfectly sensible rejection of the code is not a crash.

Answer (score 2):

According to § 14.7.2/15 this is undefined behavior:

> 15
>   There is an implementation-defined quantity that specifies the
>   limit on the total depth of recursive instan- tiations, which could
>   involve more than one template. The result of an infinite recursion in
>   instantiation is undefined.

So I agree with user657267 that either compiler can be "correct". I got the answer from [hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7435448) although I use standard n3337.